# My items on steam are still being held despite having authenticator for over a week

Tags: steam

I have had the steam authenticator for over a week however when I attempt to trade it puts the item on hold for 8 days. how do I stop this?

Comment: Is your account in good standing (no VAC bans or anything like that)? When you say "attempt to trade", do you mean trading as in inviting someone to trade or trading as in posting something on the marketplace?

Answer (score 3):

Steam guard has to be enabled for 15 days before you can trade items through the community market.

> Steam Guard Only Recently Enabled
>
> If you have recently enabled Steam Guard via email on your account,
>   you will be unable to use the Community Market for the 15 days after
>   Steam Guard was enabled. Removing Steam Guard or disabling and
>   re-enabling Steam Guard will also trigger this restriction.

[From the steam website](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-edfm-2932#recentsteamguard)